# Error Number: 1066 active record codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter

I'm trying pagination with `codeigniter` and I've got this message:

> Error Number: 1066
>   Not unique table/alias: 'albuns'

Model:

```
function get_titles($per_pg, $offset)<br />
{   
$this->db->select('albuns.*', 'players.name', 'players.id AS artistid', FALSE);<br />
$this->db->from('albuns');<br />
$this->db->join('players', 'albuns.player_id = players.id', 'inner');<br />
$this->db->order_by('albuns.ano', 'asc');<br />
$query = $this->db->get('albuns', $per_pg, $offset);<br />
return $query->result();<br />  
}

$per_pg = 20 and $config['per_page'] = $per_pg, on Controller;<br/>
$offset = $this->uri->segment(3); on Controller<br /><br />
```

Answer (score 0):

You have selected table "albuns" two times:

```
function get_titles($per_pg, $offset)
{   
    $this->db->select('albuns.*', 'players.name', 'players.id AS artistid', FALSE);
    //$this->db->from('albuns');
    $this->db->join('players', 'albuns.player_id = players.id', 'inner');
    $this->db->order_by('albuns.ano', 'asc');
    $query = $this->db->get('albuns', $per_pg, $offset);
    return $query->result();
}
```

Hope it helps